# Torch optimisers with different scaled parameters

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, torch

I am trying to optimise parameter values using a torch optimiser but the parameters are on vastly different scales. i.e., one parameter has values in the thousands while others are between 0 and 1. For example in this made up case there are two parameters - one has an optimal value of 0.1 and the other an optimal value of 20. How can I modify this code so it applies a sensible learning rate to each parameter say 1e-3 and 0.1?

```
import torch as pt
# Objective function
def f(x, y):
    return (10 - 100 * x) ** 2 + (y - 20) ** 2 
# Optimal parameters
print("Optimal value:", f(0.1, 20))
# Initial parameters
hp = pt.Tensor([1, 10])
print("Initial value", f(*hp))
# Optimiser
hp.requires_grad = True
optimizer = pt.optim.Adam([hp])
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = f(*hp)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
hp.requires_grad = False
print("Final parameters:", hp)
print("Final value:", f(*hp))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`torch.optim.Optimizer` class accepts a list of dictionaries in the `params` argument as the parameter groups. In each dictionary, you need to define `params` and other arguments used for this parameter group. If you do not provide a specific argument in the dictionary, the original arguments passed to the `Optimizer` will be used instead. Refer to the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#per-parameter-options) for more information.

Here is the updated code:

```py
import torch as pt


# Objective function
def f(x, y):
    return (10 - 100 * x) ** 2 + (y - 20) ** 2


# Optimal parameters
print("Optimal value:", f(0.1, 20))
# Initial parameters
hp = pt.Tensor([1]), pt.Tensor([10])
print("Initial value", f(*hp))
# Optimiser
for param in hp:
    param.requires_grad = True
# eps and betas are shared between the two groups

optimizer = pt.optim.Adam([{"params": [hp[0]], "lr": 1e-3}, {"params": [hp[1]], "lr": 0.1}])
# optimizer = pt.optim.Adam([{"params": [hp[0]], "lr": 1}, {"params": [hp[1]], "lr": 2.2}])

n = 5
for i in range(n):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = f(*hp)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
for param in hp:
    param.requires_grad = False
print("Final parameters:", hp)
print("Final value:", f(*hp))
```

Try using `{"lr": 1}` and `{"lr": 2.2}` for the first and second parameters, respectively. It will result in the final value of 19.9713.